# Is it possible to use shuffle in resample?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm doing Fold validation using three dataset merged in one pandas dataframework. I'm creating different samples of 20k, 40k and 60k records.

```
X, y = resample (X, y, n_samples=20000, replace=False, stratify=y)
```

I was wandering if using `resample` the records are randomly selected or if they are selected according to the sequence as they are in the data frame. If so, make sense to use `shuffle` parameter like `X, y = resample (shuffle(X, y, n_samples=20000, replace=False, stratify=y))`

Comment: What do the `resample` docs say?

Comment: There's the ```random_state``` parameter. But then, if I'll go to specify the value ```random_state=10```, what does it mean?

Comment: This is a different question altogether; please google "random number generator" and "random seed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to ask for shuffling manually; the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.resample.html) shows that the data is indeed shuffled by default, and you can specify a seed for reproducibility (emphasis added):

> **random_state : *int, RandomState instance or None, optional (default=None)***
>
> The seed of the pseudo random number generator to use when **shuffling** the data.